# How to sequence and re-sequence child records via Apex?

Tags: apex, trigger

For example, price items is a child obj that would re-evaluate its sequence number to be assigned for each child record based on price ranges entered (seq 1, 0-10, seq 2, 10-20, etc). I envision this as a "clean-up" button so when users load data the sequence may be out of order with sequence number they are inputting.  They can click an auto-re-sequence button to re-sequence the records correctly.

Working Code:

```
    public without sharing class Resequence {

    public resequence(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

    }


//variables

id tierid=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id'); //get parentid
list<tiered_pricing_configuration_item__c> oldtierlist = new list<tiered_pricing_configuration_item__c>(); //deletes old tiers
list<tiered_pricing_configuration_item__c> tier1 = new list <tiered_pricing_configuration_item__c>(); //updates lowest tier
list<tiered_pricing_configuration_item__c> clones = new list <tiered_pricing_configuration_item__c>();//copies all tiers > tier1
list<tiered_pricing_configuration_item__c> newtierslist = new list <tiered_pricing_configuration_item__c>();//inserts new tiers
list<tiered_pricing_configuration_item__c> updatetc = new list <tiered_pricing_configuration_item__c>();//update parent to disable resequence

set<Decimal> range = new set <Decimal>(); //stores lowest tier start range
set<Id> dels = new set <Id>();//stores old tier ids for deletion

public pagereference resequence(){

if(CheckRecursive.run=true){ //check recursion
    checkrecursive.run=false;

list<Tiered_Pricing_Configuration_Item__c>  titem=[Select Id, Tier_Sequence__c, Tiered_Pricing_Configuration__c, Tier_Range_Start__c 
  From Tiered_Pricing_Configuration_Item__c Where Tiered_Pricing_Configuration__c  = :tierid 
  Order by Tier_Range_Start__c ASC];//query all tiers for triggered parent record and sort by range

  AggregateResult[] MinResults = [Select MIN(Tier_Range_Start__c)mini FROM Tiered_Pricing_Configuration_Item__c Where
    Tiered_Pricing_Configuration__c =: tierid];//pull lowest tier range

 For(Tiered_Pricing_Configuration_Item__c ti :titem) {//loop through all tiers to compare lowest range
   Integer Minrange = Integer.valueOf(MinResults[0].get('mini')); 

      if(ti.tier_range_start__c == Minrange) {

      range.add(ti.tier_range_start__c);

      ti.Tier_Sequence__c = 1;

      tier1.add(ti);

        }
      }
update tier1;

list<Tiered_Pricing_Configuration_Item__c> largerange = [select id From Tiered_Pricing_Configuration_Item__c 
Where tier_range_start__c NOT IN: range AND Tiered_Pricing_Configuration__c =: tierid
Order by Tier_Range_Start__c ASC];//query for all tiers greater than tier1

/*For(Tiered_Pricing_Configuration_Item__c ti: largerange) {//loop through largerange to store copy and ids for deletion

dels.add(ti.Id);
clones.add(ti);

}*/

/*list<Tiered_Pricing_Configuration_Item__c> oldtiers = [Select Id from Tiered_Pricing_Configuration_Item__c where Id IN: dels];

For(Tiered_Pricing_Configuration_Item__c del: oldtiers) {//loop through set in list to delete

oldtierlist.add(del);

}

Delete oldtierlist;*/

For(tiered_pricing_configuration_item__c large: largerange) {
large.Tier_Sequence__c = NULL; 

oldtierlist.add(large);
}   

update oldtierlist; 

AggregateResult[] MaxResults = [SELECT MAX(Tier_Sequence__c)maxi 
FROM Tiered_Pricing_Configuration_Item__c 
WHERE Tiered_Pricing_Configuration__c =: tierid]; //pull tier1

Integer newMaxNum;

if(newMaxNum == null)
{

        newMaxNum = Integer.valueOf(MaxResults[0].get('maxi')) + 1;
    }

for(Tiered_Pricing_Configuration_Item__c newitems : oldtierlist) { //loop through new list to set values for new tiers

     newitems.Tier_Sequence__c = newMaxNum ; // Already incremented by 1, above

  newtierslist.add(newitems);

  newMaxNum++;
  }

   update newtierslist;


   }
     checkrecursive.run = true;

//Return to the parent page

PageReference ref =  new PageReference('/'+tierid);

return ref;
   }
}
```

Comment: This question is 1. too broad and 2. doesn't show that you've done any work towards the problem. If you have some work done, we can help you, but this is place is not for people to write your code for you.

Comment: Updated the original post with code.

Comment: Well, this is close but what is happening is that it correctly assigns the lowest tier, sequence 1 but all the remainders are assigned sequence 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code, there are many things to clean up:

The approach to delete all the old records and then create new ones is not preferable to selecting and updating the existing records.

You never increase the value of the iterator from 1 to maxnum. You seem to find the size of the records list you want to number/sequence, but then you seem to just assign the same number to all of them.

My advice: Step back and try it again from scratch. Write pseudocode. Use the standard controller as it should be used, by assigning a Tiered_Pricing_Configuration__c variable and then working off of that instead of using the tierid variable.

The general approach is to use a traditional for loop with an iteration variable and to assign the value of that variable to each record in your list.

And to repeat myself: Consider updating instead of deleting. It will make the system run faster and will allow you to maintain some record relationships in the future, should that be a requirement.

Comment: Thank you David for looking it over and where I should focus.  I will keep all these tips in mind.

Comment: I accomplished by two updates where I'm updating to null then looping with newMaxNumber (Integer.valueOf(MaxResults[0].get('maxi')) + 1;) integer var to iterate the sequence.  Both pieces are working perfectly now.  Seeing I am banned from posting an answer, I will update the above with the working code.

Comment: Question seems open now. If my answer helped, please mark it as accepted so that others can learn from this post @sfdev09